# Check if the user logs on

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

In dotNet MVC applications, I would like to know how to check if the user is already logged on or not.
I would like to redirect the logon users to an authenticated Index page not the Index page in the Home controller right after he logs on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel Model)
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return RedirectToAction(...);
    }

    .. login logic

    return View(Model);
}
```

Note that you can also do this with forms authentication in web.config.